# Android MediaPlayer live audio streaming : how to know if a live streaming URL can't be streamed?

Tags: java, android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I have an app to stream live audio streams.

My question is : how to check if a live streaming url can't be streamed ?

There are several reasons why an url can't be streamed :

- totally wrong url which points to nothing
- url which does not point to an audio stream (but to an image for example)
- url relative to an audio stream which cannot be streamed because the audio format is not compatible with android MediaPlayer
- probably many other reasons...

If possible, I would like to check if an url can be streamed by Android MediaPlayer without launching the buffering/preparing process.

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: please provide the solution i also stuck in the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to check if a given remote URL is alive is to do a HTTP request and check the response header.

However, this will only tell you if the URL is alive, but no if it's a valid streamable resource or not.

Your question asks if it is is possible to check for the latter without starting the buffering process. As far as I know, there is no way.

Your best bet is to prepare a MediaPlayer object asynchronously (via [prepareAsync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync())) and register a [MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener)). Don't register a setOnPreparedListener() if you don't want to play the media after it is done pre-buffering. However, do note that the OnErrorListener will not be called if the stream URL is valid.

Your best bet for just plain checking is to register both OnErrorListener and OnPreparedListener and call your own callback depending on which one of the two was called first.